# PARTITION TO PIVOT Table in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot-table, window-functions

I have a love of windowing functions and as such I have used the simple row_number() function to split some data based on an employeeID.  What I have written, works, but I can't help thinking that it could be written using PIVOT.  Here's the code:-

```
WITH [Roles] AS
(
    SELECT a.EmployeeID, a.StaffRole,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.EmployeeID ORDER BY a.StaffRole) AS RowNum
     FROM [GCHHS_Reporting].[dbo].[CathLab_Staff] a
)
SELECT a.EmployeeID, b1.StaffRole AS SR#1, b2.StaffRole AS SR#2, b3.StaffRole AS SR#3, b4.StaffRole AS SR#4, b5.StaffRole AS SR#5 FROM [GCHHS_Reporting].[dbo].[CathLab_Staff] a
    INNER JOIN [Roles] b1
        ON a.EmployeeID = b1.EmployeeID AND b1.RowNum = 1
    LEFT JOIN [Roles] b2
        ON a.EmployeeID = b2.EmployeeID AND b2.RowNum = 2
    LEFT JOIN [Roles] b3
        ON a.EmployeeID = b3.EmployeeID AND b3.RowNum = 3
    LEFT JOIN [Roles] b4
        ON a.EmployeeID = b4.EmployeeID AND b4.RowNum = 4
    LEFT JOIN [Roles] b5
        ON a.EmployeeID = b5.EmployeeID AND b5.RowNum = 5
```

The code above displays the role that each employee has taken up since the beginning of time.  So, my question is; is there a PIVOT way of doing this?

Here is a sample of the original data:-

[image: Original Data]

Here is a sample of the window-'functioned' data:-

[image: 'Windowed' data]

Any ideas or is how I've done it, the best way?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be much more easily achieved than using a 5 scans of your table. Rather than using a `PIVOT`, I find some conditional aggregation is much easier:

```
WITH [Roles] AS(
    SELECT CLS.EmployeeID,
           CLS.StaffRole,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CLS.EmployeeID ORDER BY CLS.StaffRole) AS RowNum
    FROM [GCHHS_Reporting].[dbo].[CathLab_Staff] CLS --a? CathLab doesn't start with "a".
)
SELECT R.EmployeeID,
       MAX(CASE R.RowNum WHEN 1 THEN R.StaffRole END) AS SR1,
       MAX(CASE R.RowNum WHEN 2 THEN R.StaffRole END) AS SR2,
       MAX(CASE R.RowNum WHEN 3 THEN R.StaffRole END) AS SR3,
       MAX(CASE R.RowNum WHEN 4 THEN R.StaffRole END) AS SR4,
       MAX(CASE R.RowNum WHEN 5 THEN R.StaffRole END) AS SR5
FROM Roles R --nor does Roles begin with a "b"
GROUP BY R.EmployeeID;
```

I couldn't test this against your data (as it's an image), but I did a small sample which returned the results were were after. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5e0f6bb2e76e72037d30e74b2e579b80)

Answer (score 0):

`PIVOT` does make most sense, if you want to calculate some measures in your query. In your simple example a case statement is sufficient as metioned by Larnu.

Comment: Yes, I thought so, but then how would I implement that in this instance?  A PIVOT requires a summation or grouping calculation of some kind, but this data is more categorical.  There's nothing to calculate.  This is why I used a windowing function.

Comment: Hi, sorry for answering late. I have to admit that I do not understand your follow up question.  Hold you please refine it?

Comment: Don't worry about it, requirements changed, but thanks for replying.  :)